# SNAT DNAT в iptables

Tags: iptables

Задача:
Полученный UDP-пакет на 192.168.100.101 на порт 4444 (интерфейс eth0) перенаправить на 192.168.1.7, порт 4444 c ip адреса 192.168.1.101 интерфейса eth1.
Сделать это с испльзованием iptables (а именно в таблице nat цепочки PREROUTING и POSTROUTING).

Для этого я делаю следующее:

1. на одном интерфейсе выставляю 192.168.100.101/24 (eth0), на втором 192.168.1.101/24 (eth1)
2. добавляем LOG в цепочки, чтобы иметь хоть какой-то контроль прохождения пакетов.
   Нас интересуют цепочки PREROUTING и POSTROUTING в таблице nat, INPUT и FORWARD в таблице filter, ну и PREROUTING с FORWARD таблицы mangle

Сейчас (без использования DNAT и SNAT), получив UDP-пакет на порт 4444, мы увидим (в DMESG), что он прошёл по следующему пути:
PREROUTING(mangle)->PREROUTING(nat)->INPUT(filter)->... и так до локального процесса. здесь все верно.

3. Теперь добавим DNAT:

   sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.100.101 -p udp --dport 4444 --to-destination 192.168.1.7:4444

сейчас при принятии пакета на порт 44444 следующая цепочка:
PREROUTING(mangle)->PREROUTING(nat)->????
теперь не заходит в INPUT(filter) что верно, но и не заходит FORWARD(mangle) и FORWARD(filter). ПОЧЕМУ?
Естественно пакет не был доставлен на 192.168.1.7

4. разрешим отправку данных попавших на интерфейс eth0 FORWARD

   sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -d 192.168.100.101 -p udp --dport 4444 -j ACCEPT
5. подменим IP источника UDP-пакета

   sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp --dport 4444 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.101:4455

но ситуацию это не изменит:
PREROUTING(mangle)->PREROUTING(nat)->????
я не попадаю в цепочку FORWARD таблиц mangle и filter. Почему?
В идеале должно же быть (учитывая логи которые написаны)
PREROUTING(mangle)->PREROUTING(nat)->FORWARD(mangle)->FORWARD(filter)->POSTROUTING(nat) так?
или для маршрутицации нужно что-то разрешить еще или доустановить? ufw отключен.
Линуха работает в виртуалке с двумя виртуальными интерфейсами в режиме моста.

```
Спасибо
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). начните с заголовка.

Comment: Для чего нужно перенаправить udp пакет с одного интерфейса на другой?, что будет делать второй интерфейс с этим пакетом?

Comment: Это просто попытка разобраться с iptables.скажем с задачей перенаправить принятый udp пакет с одного порта на другой в пределах одного хоста проблем не возникло. Для этого использовался REDIRECT в таблице nat